# I want to group mongoDB documents by username where a specific field matches so that the output is all the documents grouped by username

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

My collection is like:

```
{
  {
    username : "user A",
    resourceID : 1,
    TTL : 202101
  },
  
  {
    username : "user A",
    resourceID : 2,
    TTL : 202101
  },

  {
    username : "user A",
    resourceID : 3,
    TTL : 202102
  },

  {
    username : "user B",
    resourceID : 4,
    TTL : 202101
  }

}
```

Now I want all the documents with TTL=202101 grouped by user such that output is:

```
{
  user A : { {resourceID:2}, {resourceID:3} }
  user B : { {resourceID:4} }
}
```

What would be the mongoDB pipeline for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using following pipeline you might be able get similar result. Have to use *$addToSet* accumulator operator conjuction with group aggregation stage.

```
[{
   $match: {
      TTL: 202101
   }
  }, {
    $group: {
      _id: "$username",
      resourceID: { 
         $addToSet: "$resourceID" 
      }
    }
 }]
```